Trouble Opening MARS MIPS Simulator
I am attempting to open MARS MIPS simulator to use for class. I downloaded the .jar file from the link the professor provided. I also installed JDK 22. I tried directly opening the .jar file from downloads as the professor did in his demonstration, it did not work for me. I also moved the file to my desktop,as he said that could be a solution, did not work either. I currently have VS code as a placeholder for the application used to open it in the image provided below. Is there a configuration that needed to be done after the JDK installation?


Did you try the OpenJDK option?

@ggorlen Yes, however, that was a result of me going into my comptuer's "programs" directory and picking Java as the application to open it with. It did not work.

Can you provide details on "not work"? Any particular error message or behavior? You might need to reinstall Java.

@ggorlen the JDK option I chose would attempt to open the file by opening the CMD. The CMD would immediately shut down not even a second after attempting to open it.
